# Isolate Changes in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

Here's how I add the the `DbContext` service in ASP.NET Core Startup:

```
services.AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

services.AddScoped<ClassA, ClassA>();
services.AddScoped<ClassB, ClassB>();
```

**ClassA - Method1**

```
_dbContext.EntityX.Add(new EntityX { ... });

var product = ClassB.GetProduct(key);

_dbContext.EntityY.Add(new EntityY { Product = product });

_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

**ClassB - GetProduct**

```
//Check product if it exists in the database
//Else, get details of the product from a Web API

var newProduct = new Product{ ... }
_dbContext.Products.Add(newProduct );

_dbContext.SaveChanges();

return newProduct;
```

I'll be honest and tell you I haven't tried running this yet, these codes are stripped (heavily) down version of the real code for brevity.

**My questions are:**

1) Do I have the same `DbContext` in both `ClassA` and `ClassB`? Is that guaranteed?

2) If both `ClassA` and `ClassB` have the same `DbContext`, will the `SaveChanges` in `ClassB` affects the `EntityX` I added in `ClassA`?

3) What should I do to isolate changes in `ClassA` and `ClassB`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I have the same `DbContext` in both `ClassA` and `ClassB`? Is that guaranteed?

The database context are registered as scoped dependencies, that means that the instance is shared during the handling of a single incoming request. Every request will get its own dependency injection scope, so within a single request, you are guaranteed to get the *same* database context instance.

On the other hand, you are also guaranteed to get individual database contexts for separate requests.

> If both `ClassA` and `ClassB` have the same `DbContext`, will the `SaveChanges` in `ClassB` affect the `EntityX` I added in `ClassA`?

The short answer to that is yes. Since it’s a single database context, there is also a single collection of entities that are being tracked. So if you ran `ClassA.Method1` first and did not have a `SaveChanges` call there, and then ran `ClassB.Method2`, the `SaveChanges()` in the latter would also save the changes from the first method.

While this may sound problematic, in practice it usually is not: A request is typically handled as part of a controller action, so there is a very clear control flow. As such, there isn’t any parallel processing, and as long as you always “clean up” the context after using it (e.g. by calling `SaveChanges()`) there will be no problem.

On the opposite hand, you can also use this to your advantage and share transactions throughout the handling of your request without your methods knowing that they are part of a transaction.

> What should I do to isolate changes in `ClassA` and `ClassB`?

Think about whether you actually need isolation. The only way your `Method2` could impact `Method1` is when `Method1` performed changes to entities that are not saved. And if you are doing that, then you are likely misusing your entities anyway. Usually, a method should complete its work on entities, without leaving a dirty state behind.

Comment: _While this may sound problematic, in practice it usually is not_: 1. problematic when using asynchronous("parallel") execution. 2. will become problematic because you start building logic which depend on a feature, that contexts are shared, which will makes logic and code difficult to follow after time.

Comment: @Fabio (1) Asynchronous != parallel. And if you are doing concurrent stuff while handling a request, you will have other problems and things to keep in mind anyway. (2) I said that you should clean up after working with the context, so no, you are not depending on that functionality.

Comment: sorry, wasn't clear. I tried to use "parallel" in a quotes. By that I meant that asynchronous will provide possibility to run queries almost simultaneously (Not in parallel, still on same thread), but asynchronous execution time of two queries will be less then one after another. Which with scoped DbContext will not be possible without "hacking" with settings. Another caveat is you are not able to use Scoped DbContext in the `IHostedService` when you decide to use that.

Comment: 3. When two different classes will be updating same entity by using `Attach(new Entity { Id = id, Property = new-value})` - then you will end up with checking does entity already exists in the DbContext before using `Attach`.

Comment: I am sorry, my main point is: Using transient DbContext will makes you life simpler. Even better create new Context for every query where possible (with `using` statement), then yo will have full freedom of using different technical approaches in your code.

Comment: But what if SaveChanges throws an exception?
In that case dirty DbContext is passed to other services

Comment: @hex If `SaveChanges` throws, nothing is committed on the database and (hopefully) the exception will intercept the remaining execution anyway.